# What does select 1 do?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some code and wanted to make it a learning experience. I would like to ask what a select 1 does?

The first 5 lines look like someone is using a calendar function to get the yr, fiscal quarter, fiscal week then extract records if they exist in a table. I am not sure about what you would get other than you would get the yr, quarter, and week information and a column of 1's where the select 1 inner query found something. Could someone please help me with my interpretation of what is being returned? Thank you in advance. Oh, i should note that the calendar function is probably being used to truncate extra data that is returned from using the calendar function. Someone probably just wants something like June 1, 2016 rather then the minutes and seconds displayed.

Here is the code snippet:

```
select calendar, fiscal_yr, fiscal_qtr, fiscal_week from dim_date_weeks
Where exists (select 1 from dim_date cw
    where cw.calendar_date_Dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)
    and weeks.fin_qtr=cq.fin_qtr
        and weeks.fiscalweek= cw.fiscal_week
    )
union
select dlw.calendar_date, dlw.fiscalyr, dlw.fin_qtr,fiscal_week from dim_date dlw join
(select top 1 lw.fiscal_yr, lw.fin_qtr, fiscal_week from dim_date lw
    where lw.calendar=date < (select min(calendar_date)from dim_date_weeks
                        where exists (select 1 from dim_date cw
                                where date_Dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)
                                and weeks.fin_qtr=cq.fin_qtr
                                    and weeks.fiscalweek= cw.fiscal_week
                                )
                        )
    order by lw.calendar_date desc
```

Comment: Could you please help me understand a little more context? The first 5 or so lines has a select that is looking for: calendar, fiscal_yr, fiscal_qtr, fiscal_week. So are you saying that that select is returned along with a another column of 1's if the second select statement had anything to return? Or maybe your saying the first select and embedded select will return a column with a 1 in it for ever record that meets the criteria? I am trying to figure out what i would see on the computer screen.

Comment: You're trying to comment on one of the answers I assume?

Comment: I added to my answer to explain in more detail. If you still don't understand, I recommend doing some research on `exists` queries.

Answer (score 9):

`SELECT 1` just selects a 1, of course.  What it's used for in this case is testing whether any rows exist that match the criteria: if a row exists that matches the WHERE clause, then it returns 1, otherwise it returns nothing.

That's a common construct in `WHERE EXISTS` clauses, since you don't really want to return anything except the literal fact that the row exists.

---

Looking at this in more detail, let's show exactly what is happening.

Let's look at the first part only, the second part is sufficiently similar to be irrelevant.  So your query is:

```
select calendar, fiscal_yr, fiscal_qtr, fiscal_week 
  from dim_date_weeks
  where exists 
    (select 1 
      from dim_date cw
      where cw.calendar_date_Dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)
            and weeks.fin_qtr=cq.fin_qtr
            and weeks.fiscalweek= cw.fiscal_week
    )
```

Setting aside the detail that `weeks` is undefined, we'll assume that is really `dim_date_weeks`:

First, this is selecting rows from `dim_date_Weeks`.

Then, for each row in `dim_date_weeks`, it is querying `dim_date`, and finding all rows that have a `fin_qtr` that matches this row's `fin_Qtr` in `weeks`, and have a `fiscal_week` that matches this row's `fiscalweek` in `weeks`, and also have a 'true' value returned from that `calendar_date_dateadd` function (or that is a typo, more likely, and there's some comparison between `cw.calendar_Date` and a result of the native `DateAdd` function).

If that query returns any rows, then `exists` returns `true`, and that row is added to the result set.  If it returns no rows, then `exists` returns `false` and that row is not added to the result set.

Now, you'll note that there is no discussion of the `1` here.  That's because it is irrelevant. Look at the [documentation of EXISTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx); all it says is:

> Returns TRUE if a subquery contains any rows.

So it doesn't matter at all *what* you select.  This isn't like `select count()` where it does matter what's inside that parenthesis if the column is nullable and contains nulls; here, it's just *rows* that matter.  So the writer followed a stylistic choice to put `1` there.  Others (like the SQL Server documentation) might put `select *` there.  Really you can select anything that's legal to select.  It's not actually going to put that data anywhere; none of the information from the inner `EXISTS` query is put on the result set.  Only the fact that it's true or false.

---

Ultimately, this is essentially the same as doing an `inner join` between the original `from` table and the `exists` inner query, and just not selecting anything from it.  So the following would more-or-less return the same thing, if `cw` only returns one row per each `weeks` row (if they have a one to one relationship):

```
select weeks.calendar, weeks.fiscal_yr, weeks.fiscal_qtr, weeks.fiscal_week
  from dim_date_weeks weeks
  inner join
  (select 1 
     from dim_date
     where calendar_date_Dateadd(...)
  ) cw
  on cw.fin_qtr=weeks.fin_qtr
  and cw.fiscal_week=weeks.fiscalweek
```

If they don't have a one to one relationship, or many to one where cw is the one, then this will not return the same thing, and is probably why the `exists` query was done in the first place.  But you get the idea.

Note that I put `1` there also, but could've just as easily put `*` or `fin_Qtr` or anything else legal to return.  You can always return a constant, in which case a constant will be returned one for every valid row, after all.

---

Let's actually see that in action, just for fun.  Assuming this isn't a server that will mind a query being run against it frivolously, run this:

```
select 1
  from dim_date
```

What do you get?  A lot of 1s, probably.  (Might be a good idea to put `top 1000` or something in there if `dim_Date` is big.)  In fact, if you did a count of rows on `dim_date`, and did a count of those `1`s, you'd get the same number (if everything ran properly).

Comment: wow you went very depth on this one. I only try to answer the main question, but after checking your query. most likely `weeks` refers to `dim_date_weeks` other wise the `exists` condition will be the same for all the rows. So will bring all the rows or zero rows. And the fieldnames using on the where match the outter select.

Comment: Hi Joe, Many thanks for your explanation. I am also sure it helped others too. I appreciate the detail and time you spent to answer my question. I think I have a better understanding now. As soon as I get my ms sql server up and running again I will practice. Thank you! Andrew

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT 1` just return `1` , that is just a constant so the query return something and the `EXISTS` return true.

You can use anything. `1` is just the common one and because is a constanst is very fast.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 1 returns 1. and number of rows is equal to number of rows your query return.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 1 FROM tablename where condition

- if you need to count a rows from the object like tablename then it is very useful it 
  returns a whole column that contains only 1's.
- if youput any where condition in the select statement then it retunrs result as per your 
  where condition
- you just know that how many columns is affected by your select statement.